# What happens inside the orbital when energy provided to electron is not sufficient for it to change orbitals?

Tags: energy, electrons, atoms, atomic-structure

While studying the chapter called Atomic Structure, we were introduced with Bohr's model of an Atom. Even though not all of his postulates were right, I believe some were. A doubt arose in the postulate stating energy is only absorbed or emitted when an electron jumps from one orbit to another. My query is, if the energy we supply is not sufficient for it to jump to the next orbit, what would be taking place inside the orbital? Would it absorb that energy at first, then lose it due to the centrifugal attraction and radiate it? Or would it not even absorb it and just let it pass? The way it is written in my textbook makes it sound like the electron just doesn't take the energy, or atleast that's what my interpretation of the manner was. But it's a bit weird, even though everything is in the quantum world. It's like I throw a ball at you, and you only catch it if the speed is X, but you can't measure the speed of the ball. Hence, I want to clarify if this is a misconception I have or another one of the beauties of the quantum world.

Thanks,

Ravi

Comment: "Let it pass" is the most adequate description.

Comment: In particular let it go given the context. As far you are at Bohr level, or even more advance treatment, let it go is what happens as far the electronic levels are concerned. But, as you suspect, there are other *interactions* like scattering. (I personally reserve the word Absorption for the above interlevel transitions, but the interactions I have mentioned are often described - as you did - like an absorption fast followed by re-emission, this might be justified if one is to look and formalise the inner mechanism).

Comment: "It's like I throw a ball at you, and you only catch it if the speed is X [, otherwise it passes through you]." I haven't heard that metaphor before, but I think it's quite fitting to describe absorption.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So , I think this Q is related to emission & absorption spectrum. If I pass a light through an object which it doesn’t absorb , it lets it pass but we do see the light after that .